# How to use sympy to find the relationship between X and Y

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to sympy. My ultimate goal is to plot y with respect to x.

Y is the known formula of k, m, ω

[image: check the y formula]

and `x = ω*(m/k)**0.5` is also known.

I want to know how can I plot a function of both of them.

I am not sure which direction I should proceed from. I have tried simplification, and in the handwritten calculation, M/K of the numerator and denominator should be eliminated, but I have used sympy to only achieve the same variables in the top and bottom, which makes me at a loss. I hope that you can give me a solution.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be `x = ω·√(m/k)`? Because that would simplify things a lot (just divide both the numerator and the denominator by `k²` in the expression of `y` to see `ω·√(m/k)` appear everywhere: it would become `(5-x²)/(6-7x²+6x⁴)`.

Comment: You were right!  I got this result after recalculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implicit definition of `y` and `x` in terms of parameters `omega`, `k` and `m`. Since `omega` and x are directly proportional, I would recommend solving for `omega` in terms of `x` and then replacing `omega` in `y` with that solution. That will give you `y` as a function of `x` which you can then plot. Here is a toy example:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, w, k
>>> yi = w
>>> xi = w*k
>>> yx = yi.subs(w. solve(x - xi, w)[0]); yx
x/k
>>> plot(yx.subs(k, 1), ylim=(-1,3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that's what I'm looking for! According to your description, I have successfully plotted.